# In Excel, is it possible to compare multiple dates in different cells if they have the same (current) month?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I feel like what I am trying to do is very simple, but I cannot get the formula to work in Excel. I have tried using `MONTH()` and `EOMONTH()` to compare multiple dates if they are in "this month" but I keep getting a #VALUE error.

As a background, on Sheet 1 I have multiple "date payable" cells in separate columns. I have my clients listed in separate rows and each client's row has multiple date payable columns. My goal is that on Sheet 2, I can copy over only the names of the clients and the bonuses that are payable for the current month. For the sake of simplicity, here is the basic code I finished with that is not working:

```
=IF(MONTH('Sheet 1'!B9:AG9)=MONTH(TODAY()), 'Sheet 1'!B9,"")
```

Instead of doing `B9:AG9` I have also individually separated the date fields in an `OR()` function. For example:

```
IF(OR(MONTH(cell)=MONTH(TODAY()),(MONTH(cell 2)=MONTH(TODAY())), 'Sheet 1'!B9,"")
```

Yet, it still gives me a #VALUE error. Is it because most of the fields are blank and `MONTH()`/`EOMONTH()` will only work when a field is populated (even in an `OR()` function)? Any insight and solution would help! Thanks!

Comment: could you please provide 3 or 5 of your data for each column?

Answer (score 0):

The formula looks ok to me w.r.t. errors. There are no errors in the range 'Sheet 1'!B9:AG9, right?

Wrong local (commas vs semicolons) wouldn't let you enter the formula, unknown function would yield #NAME....

I'd try the following:

- Edit each part of the formula (for example: highlight the TODAY() part and press F9 to see if it calculates it.
- Try the formula on the same sheet by removing the 'Sheet 1'! part of the formula.

Maybe these can point you in the right direction, since the formula to me looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of doing B9:AG9 I have also individually separated the date
>   fields in an OR() function. For example:
>
> IF(OR(MONTH(cell)=MONTH(TODAY()),(MONTH(cell 2)=MONTH(TODAY())),
>   'Sheet 1'!B9,"")

in the formula you have provided above you have to many 'open' parentheses
if you remove the '(' at the start or your second OR argument the formula should work.

```
=IF(OR(MONTH(cell)=MONTH(TODAY()),MONTH(cell 2)=MONTH(TODAY())), 'Sheet 1'!B9,"")
```